# Easier way to create multiple variables from table

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to get several variables from a table and currently, I'm doing this to get the variables:

```
local MyTable = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}    -- this is an example the actual script is different

local var1 = MyTable[1]
local var2 = MyTable[2]
local var3 = MyTable[3]
local var4 = MyTable[4]
local var5 = MyTable[5]
local var6 = MyTable[6]
local var7 = MyTable[7]
local var8 = MyTable[8]
local var9 = MyTable[9]
local var10 = MyTable[10]
```

I feel like there is a much faster way of doing this using `for in ipairs` or something but I can't figure it out. If you know a solution please leave a comment.
Thanks.

Comment: `local var1, var2, var3 = unpack(MyTable, 1, 3)`

Comment: is there a specific reason as to why you need every element to be it's own variable?

Comment: @kojocrash because later in the script I am doing some math on them and it's just easier to understand later. So like instead of doing `MyTable[1]=(MyTable[2]*MyTable[3])+MyTable[4]` I can just do `var1=(var2*var3)+var4`

Comment: http://xyproblem.info ?